# Installing Icarus Verilog : Should I install "MinGW dependecis (DDL libraries)"?

Tags: installation, mingw

I have just started to learn HDL. I'm trying to install Icarus Verilog together with GTK Wave.

I use Windows and download the installer from [here](https://bleyer.org/icarus/). (I downloaded : iverilog-v12-20220611-x64_setup [18.2MB])

After executing the installer and completed several settings, I reached a page to customize the components to be installed.

However, I am not sure whether should I download the option, "MinGW dependencies (DDL libraries)" because I think MinGW is already installed in my computer.

I have searched for what is this option and whether I should install, but I didn't find any answers on the Internet.

I have also searched for what is DDL libraries and MinGW. My recognition regarding "MinGW dependencies (DDL libraries)" is that this is necessary to link the Icarus Verilog and MinGW so that it is possible to manage the version of Icarus Verilog using MinGW.

However, I am still not sure whether should I install this, so I'd like to hear some suggestions on this points.Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing? It is your specific use case that determines whether or not you need this additional utility or framework. Look at what your are trying to do, carefully and thoroughly, and that will answer this question for you.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for your comment. I am a beginner of Verilog, so I just want to use the basic functions of iVerilog as wave simulator.